# Support for armv7 32-bit binaries on an aarch64 Linux kernel

Tags: linux, arm, arm64

I'm trying to determine whether a Linux aarch64 kernel can run 32-bit armv7 binaries. Various threads I've found ([1], [2], [3]) indicate that this should be possible using `CONFIG_COMPAT`, but this currently doesn't seem to be working for me, and someone [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379848/running-32-bit-arm-binary-on-aarch64-not-working-despite-config-compat?noredirect=1#comment104952024_59379848) that there may be a distinction between aarch32 binaries and armv7 binaries (i.e., the ones produced with the `arm-linux-gnueabi` and `arm-linux-gnueabihf` toolchains).

So: can older 32-bit ARMv7 EABI binaries be run on an aarch64 Linux kernel, or is `CONFIG_COMPAT` intended for some other flavor of 32-bit ARM?

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460589/armv8-running-legacy-32-bit-applications-on-64-bit-os

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648832/can-old-arm32-binary-files-be-run-on-aarch64-kernel

[3] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090351/can-i-run-an-arm32-bit-app-on-an-arm64bit-platform-which-is-running-ubuntu-16-04